# the result of density contour plot with histogram2d and matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib-basemap, contourf

i am trying to plot a 2D contour density map using histogram2d, i2d  turned the histogram output into contour plot and plotted my data with contourf but i didn't appreciated the result, since it gives me a map with a huge rectangle in the middle.
here's the code i'm using[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F76Gm.png)

```
db = 1
lon_bins = np.linspace(min(lons)-db, max(lons)+db, (max(lons)-min(lons))*100)
lat_bins = np.linspace(min(lats)-db, max(lats)+db, (max(lats)-min(lats))*100) 

h, xedges, yedges = (np.histogram2d(lats, lons,[lat_bins, lon_bins])
yi, xi = m(*np.meshgrid(lon_bins, lat_bins))
g = np.zeros(xi.shape)
g[:-1,:-1] = h
g[-1] = g[0]      # copy the top row to the bottom
g[:,-1] = g[:,0]  # copy the left column to the right
print g.shape,yi.shape,xi.shape

cs = m.contourf(yi, xi, g, cmap='Dark2')
cbar = plt.colorbar(cs, orientation='horizontal')
cbar.set_label('la densite des impacts foudre',size=18) 
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(15,15)
plt.show()
```

And here's the result i got

so my request is how to have a nicer plotting, i don't want to have that rectangle in the middle ,i want my result being more smoothed...any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer of my request,so in order to get rid of that rectangle i added this to my code  :

```
g[g==0.0] = np.nan
```

which means, the bins that have density equal to 0 wouldn't appear on the plot and it's working fine.